# Django HttpRequest vs. Request

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django. Curious to note that every "view" function has a `request` as the first parameter, but when I look for `request` object in the documentation, I got `HttpRequest` instead...

Are they the same?

If so, why bother to give two names for the same object?

Comment: The `request` parameter is of *type* `HttpRequest.

Comment: Ah ha! Another question then... Is "request" a reserved key word? Can I replace the word with another such as "rqst"?

Comment: it is not a reserved word, so you can use any identifier (it is normally passed positionally as the *first* parameter).

Comment: Thanks! Fairway & Green

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `request` parameter is an object from class `HttpRequest`.

You do not need to import the `HttpRequest` class because that parameter is not being typed. You would need to import it if you were typing it, in the following way:

```
view_example(request: HttpRequest)
```

Answer (score 5):

> Are they the same?
>   If so, why bother to give two names for the same object?

`HttpRequest` is a class, the `request` parameter to views is an instance of this class (well, it's expected to be at least).